# Access array elements from string argument in Modelica

Tags: arrays, modelica

I'm having a task in Modelica, where within a function, I want to read out values of a `record` (parameters) according to a given `string` type argument, similar to the `dictionary` type in Python.

For example I have a record containing coefficicents for different media, I want to read out the coefficients for methane, so my argument is the `string` "Methane".

Until now I solve this by presenting a second `array` in my coefficients-record storing the names of the media in `strings`. This array I parse in a for loop to match the requested media-name and then access the coefficients-array by using the found index.

This is obviously very complicated and leads to a lot of confusing code and nested for loops. Isn't there a more convenient way like the one Python presents with its `dictionary` type, where a `string` is directly linked to a value?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could try using enumerations for array indexing as described in Michael Tillers book: http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/arrays/indexing/

Comment: I guess this would be a possible solution but - to stay in the example - since my model should be applicable to several different mixtures, I cannot set up an enumeration in my code because I don't know the number and names of components in the medium beforehand. Also, how would I use the `string`-array containing the components' names to construct an `enumeration`-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different alternatives you can use. I will add the pattern I like most:

```
model M
  function index
    input String[:] keys;
    input String key;
    output Integer i;
  algorithm
    i := Modelica.Math.BooleanVectors.firstTrueIndex({k == key for k in keys});
  end index;
  constant String[3] keys = {"A","B","C"};
  Real[size(keys,1)] values = {1,2*time,3};
  Real c = values[index(keys,"B")] "Coefficient";
  annotation(uses(Modelica(version="3.2.1")));
end M;
```

The reason I like this code is because it can be made efficient by a Modelica compiler. You create a keys vector, and a corresponding data vector. The reason it is not a record is that you want the keys vector to be constant, and the values may vary over time (for a more generic dictionary than you wanted).

The compiler can then create a constant index for any constant names you want to lookup from this. This makes sorting and matching better in the compiler (since there are no unknown indexes). If there is a key you want to lookup at run-time, the code will work for this as well.

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks!